# How to write mockito junit for Resttemplate exchange method

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, resttemplate

How to write mockito junit for the method below:

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

ResponseEntity<?> execute(final String url, HttpMethod httpMethod,
                          HttpEntity<?> entityRequest,
                          String.class, 
                          Map<String, String> urlVariables){
    restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, entityRequest, responseType, urlVariables);
}
```

Please help me how to write.

Comment: You have to mock the rest template in this case. Then just mock the method call: `Mockito.when(restTemplate.exhange(...)).thenReturn(..)`. Any problems with that?

Comment: Should not the `execute` method _return_ the `exchange` result?

Comment: Would you like to test the method logic and mock the restTemplate result?

Answer (score 27):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ToTestTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private YourClass toTest;

  @Mock
  private RestTemplate template;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    toTest.execute(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), 
                   Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());

    Mockito.verify(template, Mockito.times(1))
                    .exchange(Mockito.anyString(),
                                    Mockito.<HttpMethod> any(),
                                    Mockito.<HttpEntity<?>> any(),
                                    Mockito.<Class<?>> any(),
                                    Mockito.<String, String> anyMap());
    }
 }
```

Comment: This nicely shows the mockito mechanics. Detail: You need brackets `(...)` around the type casts before the `any` calls.

Comment: But you suppose that into `YourClass` don't create a `new RestTemplate()`?

Comment: Mockito create a mock instance of the resttemplate for you

Comment: `Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 1 recorded:`

Comment: @ClaudioPomo Of course you don't do `new RestTemplate()` - it would be a hard dependency, which cannot be mocked and should be avoided in your code (even if you don't write tests at all).

Answer (score 5):

I think the most convenient and appropriate approach in this case (which is client side REST testing using `RestTemplate`) will be [`MockRestServiceServer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) provided by [Spring Testing](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) framework.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want.

One way to use mocks is to make it easier to invoke the `execute` method. For that, you can use mocked versions of the actual parameters, such as the `HttpMethod` and the `HttpEntity`. If the underlying `exchange` method requires certain behavior from these parameters, you may need to stub that in with mockito's `when` ... `thenReturn` methods.

Once these mocked parameters are setup so that you can call your `execute` methods, you will want to check that its result is correct.

For checking the returned value, you can use traditional JUnit assertions.

Furthermore, you may want to check that certain *interactions* with the mocked objects actually took place. For that you can use mockito's `verify` methods to check, for example, that some `HttpEntity` method is actually invoked.

Technically, you could also verify that the rest template's `exchange` method is called. For that you'd need to mock the RestTemplate and inject the mock in you class under test. Then you can use mockito's `verfiy` to check that `exchange` is called in the proper way. This typically is the sensible thing to do, especially if there are more methods to test in your class-under-test. For the present `execute` method it seems a bit overkill though.

Answer (score -1):

I used to get such an error. I found a more reliable solution. I have mentioned the import statements too which have worked for me. The below piece of code perfectly mocks the rest template.

```
import org.mockito.Matchers;  
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;

    HttpHeaders headers = new Headers();
    headers.setExpires(10000L);     
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("dummyString", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    when(restTemplate.exchange( Matchers.anyString(), 
            Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
            Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), 
            Matchers.<Class<String>> any())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Here the 'responseEntity' value will not be null and we can use it to perfectly assert a statement.